# Running a debounced function after user has navigated away from page

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a debounced function of 3 seconds that I send off to an API service for tracking events.

```
// api.js
import { debounce } from 'lodash'

const submitRecords = debounce(async () => {
  await API.submit({ ...data })

  // do other stuff here
}, 3000)
```

Every time there's a user interaction, my application calls `submitRecords`, waits 3 seconds, and then makes a request to the API service. The problem here is that if the user navigates away before 3 seconds, the call never gets made.

Is there a way to still send the debounced request even when the user has navigated away from the current URL? I read up on `window.onbeforeunload` but I'm not sure if it's suitable for my use case.

Comment: You could run your submit on `beforeunload` or `pagehide`, but your debounce and its delay will not be ran anymore after the user has left. You could set up a flag that says that you will update in three seconds, and if they leave the page before that it will submit. Otherwise nothing happens when you leave as the user hasnt changed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `window.onbeforeunload`.
But instead of `async/await` may be you need some another `debounce` implementation, or to do it by yourself.
It can be done with `debounce` implemented by usage `setTimeout` and storing timer somewhere globally.
In `window.onbeforeunload` check timer and if present - execute required logic.

Or you can try to use flag that indicates function in `debouncing`. Like:

```
const isDebouncing = false;
const submitRecords = () => {
  isDebouncing = true;
  debounce(async () => {
    isDebouncing = false;
    await API.submit({ ...data })

    // do other stuff here
  }, 3000)();
}

window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  if (isDebouncing) {
    // do request
  }
}
```

Note: Besides just one flag you can store another data related to `await API.submit({ ...data })`.

Note: in some cases window.onbeforeunload requires preventing event and return value, like:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
});
```

Described her: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: Using a flag to determine whether the function should be debounced or not did the trick. Thanks!